# I have a listview separated into 3 different "rows" like a instagram layout, how to click the correct image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The images sorts themselves out just like instagram but I am not sure how I should get the click on an item event just right. With my current code It always clicks on the first row (image). How can I adjust the code so it clicks on that particular image?

```
    public class info 
    {
        public  string theimage {get; set;}
        public  string theimage2 {get; set;}
        public  string theimage3 {get; set;}
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="imagesListview" RowHeight="100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                      <ViewCell.View>
                            <AbsoluteLayout>

                                <Image Source="{Binding theimage}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding theimage2}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding theimage3}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill" />
                            </AbsoluteLayout>
                      </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The code:

```
    new List<info> imagesList = new List<info> (); //my list

    public PhotoPage ()
    {
      imagesListview.ItemSelected += selectedItemClick; //i showcase this code below
      loadPhotos ();
    }
```

The code that makes the images load into the listview with the instagram-layout.

```
async void loadPhotos ()
    {

        info Info = null;
        var getInfo = await phpApi.getPhotos ();

        imagesListview.ItemsSource = null;
        imagesList = new List<info> ();

        foreach (var items in getInfo["results"]) {

            if (ndx == 0) {
                Info = new info();

                Info.theimage = items ["Photo"].ToString();
                ndx++;
            } 

            else if (ndx == 1) {
                    Info.theimage2 = items ["Photo"].ToString();
                    ndx++;
            } 

            else if (ndx == 2) {
                        Info.theimage3 = items ["Photo"].ToString();
                        imagesList.Add(Info);
                        Info = null;
                        ndx = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Info != null) {
            imagesList.Add(Info);
        }

        imagesListview.ItemsSource = imagesList;

    }
```

And this is the click I am working on but havent nailed just yet. What do I need to do in order to make it click on either image, image2 or image3.
With the current code I always get the image (first row) even if I click on the second row or third.

```
void selectedItemClick (object s, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem != null) {
            info theClickedItem = (info)e.SelectedItem;

            Navigation.PushAsync 
                (new PhotoDetailPage (theClickedItem.theimage)); //here I have the image, image2 and image3. How do I send the correct one?

        }
    }
```

The page that recieves the image.

```
  public PhotoDetailPage (string photo)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        img.Source = photo; //my image in xaml.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ListView.ItemSelected`, it only fires when a users clicks a single row in the `ListView`. Since you have added 3 `Image` rows into each `ListView` row, you will need to handle the clicks on the `Image` rows as opposed to trying to handle them on the `ListView`'s row.

Also, the reason clicking on the row always shows the first image is because you are always passing the first image in this line:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new PhotoDetailPage (theClickedItem.theimage));
```

To fix this, just comment out the `ListView.ItemSelected` event attachment like so:

```
//imagesListview.ItemSelected += selectedItemClick;
```

Then, for each `Image` you will attach a gesture recognizer to it like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding theimage}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnImageTapped"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Now just add a new `OnImageTapped()` event handler in your code-behind like this:

```
private async void OnImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {

        Image imageSender = (Image)sender;

        string imageString = (string)imageSender.BindingContext;

        await Navigation.PushAsync (new PhotoDetailPage (imageString));
}
```

Also notice in `OnImageTapped()` above, I add `async` to the method signature and then I add `await` before `Navigation.PushAsync()`. This is extremely important and is what you should be doing for any and all async methods, such as `PushAsync()` for example. There are many other methods that need to be `await`'ed like this. Never use `.Result` on an async method if you can help it.

Edit: I also notice that you are calling your async `loadPhotos()` method from the constructor and you are not awaiting it. I would highly suggest that you call that async method from your `ContentPage`'s `OnAppearing()` event since you can make `OnAppearing()` asynchronous and then you can correctly await `loadPhotos()`. So that would look like this:

```
public class PhotoPage {

    public PhotoPage() {
        //imagesListview.ItemSelected += selectedItemClick;
        //loadPhotos ();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing() {
        await loadPhotos();
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: @medvedo See edit also for a fix to your current page.

Comment: Will take a look in an hour. Not at the coding computer currently.

Comment: When I click an image I get this error: "Specified cast is not valid" on this line right here:  "string imageString = (string)imageSender.BindingContext;"

Comment: @medvedo Is `imageSender.BindingContext;` the `info` object?

Comment: I copied ur exact code: `private async void OnImageTapped(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) {

   Image imageSender = (Image)sender;

   string imageString = (string)imageSender.BindingContext;

   await Navigation.PushAsync (new PhotoDetailPage (imageString));
  }`

Comment: It is an "Image", If i replace Image with my class "info" I cannot use a bindingcontext

Comment: @medvedo And you attached the `GestureRecognizer` to your image and the `GestureRecognizer` points to that `OnImageTapped` method? Did you remove the `ItemSelected` event attachment code? If so, I am not really sure. Since your `ListView` is bound to a list of `info` objects, the 3 `Image`s in the `ListView` should automatically have their `BindingContext` set to the `info` object, which allows them to get access to the `info` object's properties, such as `info.theimage`.

Comment: Yes, i have copied the exact code as you gave me. But I keep getting this "Specified cast is not valid" error.

Comment: Does it have something to do with replacing Eventargs with "ItemTappedEventArgs" ?

Comment: @medvedo No, the `TapGestureRecognizer`'s Tapped event does not use `ItemTappedEventArgs`. You just need to find out what in the world `imageSender.BindingContext` is. Put a breakpoint there and inspect the `BindingContext` property to figure out what it is.

Comment: Replaced this code: `string imageString = (string)imageSender.BindingContext;` with this `string imageString = imageSender.BindingContext.ToString();` and I recieve no error now. But I do not see an image at the next page when I push the imagestring to the next page where I have a waiting image waiting to get that source.

Comment: @medvedo Does `imageString` have anything in it after calling `ToString()`?

Comment: After calling ToString imageString gives me this in the log: `Projectname.PhotoPage+info`